# How to extract 1st element from list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list with Stress values and its applications as tuples. It looks like this:

```
[(163.0, 0.5), (161.0, 0.5), (158.0, 1.0), (157.0, 1.0), (156.0, 2.0), (154.0, 1.0), (151.0, 0.5), (145.0, 1.0), (143.0, 0.5), (142.0, 0.5), (138.0, 0.5), (136.0, 1.0), (134.0, 1.0), (131.0, 1.0), (124.0, 1.0), (121.0, 1.0), (119.0, 1.0), (115.0, 1.0), (110.0, 1.0), (106.0, 0.5), (103.0, 0.5), (98.0, 1.0), (87.0, 1.0), (84.0, 1.0), (76.0, 2.0), (71.0, 1.0), (62.0, 1.0), (59.0, 1.0), (53.0, 1.0), (45.0, 1.0), (41.0, 1.0), (36.0, 1.0), (33.0, 1.0), (32.0, 1.0), (22.0, 1.0), (21.0, 1.0), (16.0, 1.0), (14.0, 1.0), (9.0, 1.0), (5.0, 1.0)]
```

I need to extract only the Stress values. Can someone please help me do this in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [(163.0, 0.5), (161.0, 0.5), (158.0, 1.0), (157.0, 1.0), (156.0, 2.0), (154.0, 1.0), (151.0, 0.5), (145.0, 1.0), (143.0, 0.5), (142.0, 0.5), (138.0, 0.5), (136.0, 1.0), (134.0, 1.0), (131.0, 1.0), (124.0, 1.0), (121.0, 1.0), (119.0, 1.0), (115.0, 1.0), (110.0, 1.0), (106.0, 0.5), (103.0, 0.5), (98.0, 1.0), (87.0, 1.0), (84.0, 1.0), (76.0, 2.0), (71.0, 1.0), (62.0, 1.0), (59.0, 1.0), (53.0, 1.0), (45.0, 1.0), (41.0, 1.0), (36.0, 1.0), (33.0, 1.0), (32.0, 1.0), (22.0, 1.0), (21.0, 1.0), (16.0, 1.0), (14.0, 1.0), (9.0, 1.0), (5.0, 1.0)]
>>> stresses = [a for a, _ in lst]
>>> stresses
[163.0, 161.0, 158.0, 157.0, 156.0, 154.0, 151.0, 145.0, 143.0, 142.0, 138.0, 136.0, 134.0, 131.0, 124.0, 121.0, 119.0, 115.0, 110.0, 106.0, 103.0, 98.0, 87.0, 84.0, 76.0, 71.0, 62.0, 59.0, 53.0, 45.0, 41.0, 36.0, 33.0, 32.0, 22.0, 21.0, 16.0, 14.0, 9.0, 5.0]
```